# Why is the Gitlab pipeline running a job when I my gitlab-ci.yml says it shouldn't (by means of change only)?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

This is the relevant job in the yml file:

```
#container structure test for check service stub
container-test-command-check:
  only:
    changes:
      - stub-services/check-service/**/*
  extends: container-test-command
  <<: *branches
  allow_failure: true
  variables
    CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/check-stub
  dependencies:
    - move-container-tests-check
```

My intention is that this job should only run if any files in the folder 'stub-services/check-service' have been altered. Unfortunately, it runs regardless of whether there have been any changes or not.

Here's the full yml file with non-relevant parts redacted for the sake of clarity and commercial confidentiality:

```
include:
  - '/gitlab-ci/includes.yml'
  - '/idt-test-stub/gitlab-ci.yml'

variables:
  ALPINE_VERSION: "3.16"
  NODE_VERSION: "14-alpine"
  ESLINT_CONFIG_PATH: "./.eslintrc.js"
  SOURCE_DIR: "."
  RULESET: MAVEN_CI
  BUILD_TYPE: MAVEN
  MVN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"
  MVN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2-local -f wiremock-java/pom.xml"
  MAVEN_IMAGE: "maven:3-jdk-11"

stages:
  - test
  - code-quality
  - code-test
  - code-analysis
  - verify
  - transform
  - application-build
  - image-build
  - move-container-tests
  - container-image-test
  - image-push

.branches: &branches
  only:
    - branches

todo-check:
  <<: *branches

shell-check:
  <<: *branches

lint-source:
  <<: *branches

docker-lint:
  <<: *branches

unit-test:
  <<: *branches
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 20 mins
    paths:
      - ./coverage

sonar-scanner:
  extends: .sonar-scanner-base
  <<: *branches
  stage: code-analysis

node-audit:
  <<: *branches

node-outdated:
  <<: *branches
  allow_failure: true

verify:
  <<: *branches
  stage: verify
  image: node:$NODE_VERSION
  script:
    - npm install
    - ./run-verify.sh
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker-privileged

transform:
  <<: *branches
  stage: transform
  image: node:$NODE_VERSION
  script:
    - npm install
    - ./run-transform.sh
  artifacts:
    name: "wiremock-json"
    paths:
      - stub-services/check-service/wiremock/stubs
      - stub-services/kgb-service/wiremock/stubs
     
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker-privileged

maven-package:
  <<: *branches
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./wiremock-java/target
    expire_in: 1 hour

docker-build:
  extends: .docker-build-template
  <<: *branches
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DOCKERFILE_PATH: "./Dockerfiles/Dockerfile.check-service"
        CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/check-stub
        ADD_LATEST_TAG: "true"
        ADD_GIT_TAGS: "true"
        CI_COMMIT_TAG: "${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
     
      - DOCKERFILE_PATH: "./Dockerfiles/Dockerfile.kgb-service"
        CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/kgb-service-stub
        ADD_LATEST_TAG: "true"
        ADD_GIT_TAGS: "true"
        CI_COMMIT_TAG: "${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"

  except:
   variables:
      - $PROD_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - $PROD_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - $PROD_AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  dependencies:
    - transform
    - maven-package

#sast container test for service stubs
sast-container:
  <<: *branches
  allow_failure: true
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/check-stub
      - CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/kgb-service-stub

trivy-container:
  extends: .trivy-container-base
  <<: *branches
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/check-stub
      - CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/kgb-service-stub

  allow_failure: true


#move container test json into container-tests, for check-service stub
#so container-tests folder will be picked up by container-test-command below
move-container-tests-check:
  <<: *branches
  stage: move-container-tests
  image: alpine:$ALPINE_VERSION
  script:
    - cp -R container-test-folders/check-service container-tests
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker-privileged
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - container-tests

#container structure test for check service stub
container-test-command-check:
  only:
    changes:
      - stub-services/check-service/**/*
  extends: container-test-command
  <<: *branches
  allow_failure: true
  variables:
    CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/check-stub
  dependencies:
    - move-container-tests-check

#move container test json into container-tests, for kgb-service stub
#so container-tests folder will be picked up by container-test-command below
move-container-tests-kgb:
  <<: *branches
  stage: move-container-tests
  image: alpine:$ALPINE_VERSION
  script:
    - cp -R container-test-folders/kgb-service container-tests
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker-privileged
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - container-tests

#container structure test for kgb service stub
container-test-command-kgb:
  extends: container-test-command
  only:
    changes:
      - stub-services/kgb-service/**/*
  <<: *branches
  allow_failure: true
  variables:
    CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/kgb-service-stub
  dependencies:
    - move-container-tests-kgb
```

Comment: What’s in `branches`? We need the full block to determine why this is/isn’t working. Also, what’s triggering the build?

Comment: I've updated the question with the (almost) full yml file.
The pipeline is triggered by a commit.

Comment: This shouldn’t be happening. That said, you have a very complicated build script and i may be missing something. Also I don’t have all the includes or inherits blocks. Can you recreate the issue in a new repo with a much less complicated [mre]?